# passing parametres to FXML file from the controller

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

```
 Hello I'm new to javaFX, and trying to create a simulation application of the scheduling algorithms.
```

I did the logic package, but still have problems with the UI. what i want to do is to allow the user to enter the number of jobs and in the next window i want to display text fields where he can put the executing time of each job, in other words i should display the text fields n time as the number of jobs given by the user.

this is what i did for the first interface :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" alignment="center" hgap="10" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" vgap="10" fx:controller="ui.FXMLController">
<padding><Insets bottom="10" left="25" right="25" top="25" /></padding>
 <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@fxml.css" />
  </stylesheets>
   <children>
   <Text id="welcome-text" text="Welcome" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
       <Label text="Le nombre de Processus:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
       <TextField fx:id="textField"  GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
       <Label text="Choisissez un Algorithm d'Ordonancement :" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
       <HBox alignment="bottom_right" spacing="10" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
       <Text fx:id="actiontarget" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
        <Button onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Next" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
      <MenuButton mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Algo ... " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="true" text="Fifo" onAction="#handleButtonAction" />
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Tourniquet" />
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="PCTER" />
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="PCTE" />
        </items>
      </MenuButton>
   </children>    
</GridPane>
```

this is my controller :

```
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Button button;
    @FXML
    private TextField textField;

    @FXML
    private Integer i; 

    @FXML
    public void handleButtonAction() throws IOException{

        String t = textField.getText();
        IntegerStringConverter a = new IntegerStringConverter();
        this.i = a.fromString(t);

        Parent window = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXML1.fxml"));
        Scene secondScene = new Scene(window);

        Stage stage = new Stage();

        stage.setScene(secondScene);
        stage.show();

        stage.show();
    }
}
```

i dont know if there is a way to pass parameters from the controller to the FXML file and to do a loop in the FXML.. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to request user input and create nodes in the GUI according to the input.

You can't create loops respectively control structures in a fxml file, but you can dynamically add and remove nodes (i.e. **TextFields**) by

defining a Vertical Box / Horizontal Box,

```
<VBox id="HBox" fx:id="myVBox" ...>
```

get the input as an integer,

```
int sum = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
```

and add the nodes in a for-loop,

```
for(int i=0, i<sum, i++) {
     myVBox.getChildren().add(new TextField("executing time"));
}
```

and update the view.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't do that. You have to reverse the controL flow:
The controller should create the necessary controls (labels, textfields etc.) in a loop, possibly using a different FXML, which just defines that part.

Comment: thks for the replay can you give me a hint how to do it please because i'm lost please ....